# how to define a global variable inside linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, global-variables

I am new to kernel programming and trying to implement a system call in linux kernel 3.19 which keeps track of the processes in a linked list. So every time the system call is invoked from user-space (by some wrapper function) a new process has to be added to that list.
My system call looks something like

```
asmlinkage long sys_newcall(pid_t pid)
{
    /*
     * mytasks is the name of the structure
     * kmalloc() is invoked to create an instance 
     */
    struct mytasks newTask = kmalloc(sizeof(struct mytasks), GFP_KERNEL);
    /* various checks */
    /* now adding the new instance to the list */

    list_add_tail(&(newTask->list),&(mylist->list));
    /* i have put list_head struct in my own structure to make use of above interface */
}
```

Now the `mylist` variable used above should be defined global so as to maintain the list for subsequent system calls. How to accomplish that? Do I have to declare `mylist` variable in `linux/init/main.c` or I can simply use `EXPORT_GLOBAL`. I also read about using extern but couldn't figure out where to declare and define the variable.

Comment: "*how to define a global variable inside linux kernel?*" you don't ... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using EXPORT_SYMBOL will be best as this will be visible to loadable modules also and declare it int the file in which you are using  or in a locally header file

Comment: Thank you!! I have explored that and it works fine also can u plz suggest how to initialize my variable `mylist` in this case at boot time?

Comment: you could see include/linux/list.h for all list operations. There are provided macro for it